# Xamarin.iOS custom control does not respect height constraint

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, autolayout, custom-controls

I have created a custom control with Xamarin.iOS following the following guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/templates/using_the_ios_view_xib_template/

However when I use the control on in one of my views, it ignores the height and right auto layout constraints I assigned to it at runtime, at design time all looks good. (the constraints are set using the designer).

The code of my custom control is as follows:

```
using Foundation;
using System.ComponentModel;
using UIKit;
using System;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace RidderCRM.iOS
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public partial class RidderDetailBigToSmall : UIView, IComponent
    {
        public RidderDetailBigToSmall(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        #region IComponent implementation
        public ISite Site { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler Disposed;
        #endregion IComponent implementation

        #region Icon properties
        [Export("Icon"), Browsable(true)]
        public UIImage Icon { get; set; }
        #endregion Icon properties

        #region Title properties
        [Export("Title"), Browsable(true)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Export("TitleColor"), Browsable(true)]
        public UIColor TitleColor { get; set; }
        #endregion Title properties

        #region Subtitle properties
        [Export("Subtitle"), Browsable(true)]
        public string Subtitle { get; set; }

        [Export("SubtitleColor"), Browsable(true)]
        public UIColor SubtitleColor { get; set; }
        #endregion Subtitle properties

        public override CGSize IntrinsicContentSize
        {
            get { return new CGSize(NoIntrinsicMetric, 56f); }
        }

        public new static bool RequiresConstraintBasedLayout()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void AwakeFromNib()
        {
            base.AwakeFromNib();

            if ((Site != null) && Site.DesignMode)
            {
                // Bundle resources aren't available in DesignMode
                return;
            }

            NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("RidderDetailBigToSmall", this, null);

            // At this point all of the code-behind properties should be set, specifically rootView which must be added as a subview of this view
            this.AddSubview(this.RootView);

            this.TitleLabel.Text = Title;
            this.TitleLabel.TextColor = TitleColor;

            this.SubtitleLabel.Text = Subtitle;
            this.SubtitleLabel.TextColor = SubtitleColor;

            this.IconImageView.Image = Icon;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the control placed on a view at design-time after and a screenshot of the applied constraints (note the labels and icon don't show but I read this is expected behaviour):

[image: Custom control placed on a view at design-time]

[image: Constraints put on the custom control]

Here is a screenshot of the view containing my custom control at runtime (note that the control will take up all the space to the bottom of the view):

[image: View containing the custom control at runtime]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help of the Xamarin community (@cheesebaron, @diegoxleon and @nmilcoff) I managed to solve the problem.

First of they pointed me out to the following guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/

Second they advised to ignore the .xib file and create the control in code (following the guide above).

Lastly they gave some advise on where and how to setup the auto layout constraints for all subviews used in the custom control.

I ended up with the following code:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Foundation;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace RidderCRM.iOS.CustomControls
{
    [Register("RidderDetailLabel")]
    public class RidderDetailLabel
        : UIView, IComponent
    {
        private UIImageView _iconImageView;
        private UILabel _titleLabel;
        private UILabel _subtitleLabel;

        private bool _didSetupConstraints = false;

        public RidderDetailLabel() { }

        public RidderDetailLabel(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

        #region IComponent implementation
        public ISite Site { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler Disposed;
        #endregion

        [Export("TitlePosition"), Browsable(true)]
        public TitlePosition TitlePosition { get; set; }

        [Export("Icon"), Browsable(true)]
        public UIImage Icon { get; set; }

        [Export("Title"), Browsable(true)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Export("TitleTextColor"), Browsable(true)]
        public UIColor TitleTextColor { get; set; }

        [Export("Subtitle"), Browsable(true)]
        public string Subtitle { get; set; }

        [Export("SubtitleTextColor"), Browsable(true)]
        public UIColor SubtitleTextColor { get; set; }

        public override void AwakeFromNib()
        {
            base.AwakeFromNib();

            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            _iconImageView = new UIImageView
            {
                Image = Icon,
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill,
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            };

            _titleLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = Title,
                TextColor = TitleTextColor,
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17),
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            };

            _subtitleLabel = new UILabel
            {
                Text = Subtitle,
                TextColor = SubtitleTextColor,
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12),
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            };

            AddSubview(_iconImageView);
            AddSubview(_titleLabel);
            AddSubview(_subtitleLabel);
        }

        public override void UpdateConstraints()
        {
            if (!_didSetupConstraints)
            {
                SetupConstraints();

                _didSetupConstraints = true;
            }

            base.UpdateConstraints();
        }

        private void SetupConstraints()
        {
            // Add Icon constraints
            AddConstraint(_iconImageView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(RightAnchor, -16));
            AddConstraint(_iconImageView.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(CenterYAnchor));
            AddConstraint(_iconImageView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25));
            AddConstraint(_iconImageView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(25));

            // Add Title constraints
            AddConstraint(_titleLabel.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(TopAnchor, 12));
            AddConstraint(_titleLabel.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(LeftAnchor, 16));
            AddConstraint(_titleLabel.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_iconImageView.RightAnchor, -16));
            AddConstraint(_titleLabel.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(20));

            // Add Subtitle constraints
            AddConstraint(_subtitleLabel.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_titleLabel.BottomAnchor, 3));
            AddConstraint(_subtitleLabel.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(LeftAnchor, 16));
            AddConstraint(_subtitleLabel.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_iconImageView.RightAnchor, -16));
            AddConstraint(_subtitleLabel.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(15));

        }
    }
}
```